# How to retrieve chat history from ejabberd using Strophe and Intel XDK?

Tags: chat, ejabberd, intel-xdk, strophe

I am trying to understand how should I retrieve chat history from ejabberd between 2 users? I am using Strophe client and Intel XDK. 
I am successfully sending the message, and the other user successfully receives the message. Also I have activated the mod_mam module, so I can see in my DB the entire conversation. My problem is, because I am developing a mobile app, and every time I exit the app, my conversation dissapears, what should I do to keep that conversation in my app even when I exit the app?